# Does the 1:1 sex ratio at birth apply to every human pregnancy or is it a statistical average?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, sex-chromosome

Are there genetic factors that biase the sex ratio of offsprings for each person but average to 1:1 for the entire human population, or does the 1:1 ratio apply to every single fertile person?

Comment: The ratio is not 1:1: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27582/why-do-we-have-more-male-infants-born

Comment: @kmm The question still stands -- is the ratio a statistical average or applicable to individuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio you are referring to is indeed computed aggregating multiple observations and thus it is a "statistical average".

Any individual (or couple, in this case) can have a specific ratio that differs from the average one. Many factors may affect sex ratio, among which [sperm/egg viability](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3735000/), chromosomal aberrations, and hormones misbalance are the ones usually affecting the fertility of a couple and they can also bias the sex ratio.

Many other factors can play a role.
[Different populations have slightly different sex-ratio](https://www.rbmojournal.com/article/S1472-6483(10)60378-1/pdf) and even [smoking can skew the sex ratio!](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/20/9/2517/2356788)

Comment: The question is not very well asked but I suppose the OP does not ask whether any given couple can have more offspring of one sex than of the other but rather whether there is genetic variance in the sex-ratio.

Comment: @Remi.b I have interpreted the question differently. I will wait for the OP to comment to this answer or to clarify the question. If needed, I will adjust my answer.